# ng-model not updating object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form that's meant to let the user edit some information

My problem is with `<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-repeat="info in item.Question" ng-model="info"/>`. When I click on the save button, the logs (example copied below) tell me it's not updating the model. Can anyone see why?

I read on a few other questions that ng-model needs an object.property value, but I don't see how i can apply that here

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" ng-show="item.edit">

<div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">
        <form class="form-group form-inline">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="item.Name" />
            <span class="badge pull-right">&#8356;<input class="form-control" type="number" step="any" ng-model="item.Price" /></span>
        </form>
    </h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="item.Desc" />
    <hr>
    <div class="col-md-11">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-repeat="info in item.Question" ng-model="info"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <a href="" ng-click="cat.newQuestion(item)" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-footer">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <a href="" ng-click="cat.change(item)" class="btn btn-success">Save</a>
        <a href="" ng-click="item.edit = false" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</a>
        <a href="" ng-click="cat.deleteItem(item)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

an example of the log from the `change()` function:

```
app.js:39 Object {ID: "10", Name: "New User", Price: 0, Desc: "Create a new user for the Quarriers network", CatID: "3"…}$$hashKey: "object:50"CatID: "3"Desc: "Create a new user for the Quarriers network"ID: "10"Name: "New User"Price: 0Question: "username,"edit: true
app.js:40 stringing
app.js:46 Object {ID: "10", Name: "New User", Price: 0, Desc: "Create a new user for the Quarriers network", CatID: "3"…}$$hashKey: "object:50"CatID: "3"Desc: "Create a new user for the Quarriers network"ID: "10"Name: "New User"Price: 0Question: "username,"edit: true__proto__: Object
```

Comment: try this: `<div ng-repeat="info in item.Question"><input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="info"/></div>`

Comment: if i have 7 items in Question, that will literally create 7 div's with 7 textboxes inside each :P (I did try it to be sure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change `Question` to an object with a property you can use the following:

```
<input ng-repeat="info in item.Question track by $index" ng-model="item.Question[$index]"/>
```